# adding a new column to a tibble after bind_rows from a list

Tags: r

I have some data in a list and I am trying to bind it to a data frame.

What I have so far is the following:

```
bind_rows(myData) %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal")
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 50
  ..2013.Jul ..2013.Aug ..2013.Sep ..2013.Oct ..2013.Nov ..2013.Dec ..2014.Jan ..2014.Feb ..2014.Mar ..2014.Apr
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1   5.87e-10    6.48e-9    5.18e-8    3.90e-8    1.35e-8   10.00e-1    8.89e-1   2.88e-10    8.48e-9   1.79e-10
2  10.00e- 1    8.75e-1    6.12e-1   10.00e-1    8.52e-9    2.06e-9    6.87e-9   1.73e-10    1.02e-8   2.01e-10
3   1.18e- 9    1.40e-8    2.64e-8    2.76e-8    5.56e-9    4.24e-9    1.35e-8   2.01e-10    8.91e-9   1.71e-10
4   2.66e- 9    1.25e-1    3.09e-7    4.72e-8    3.40e-9    1.12e-8    3.68e-8   2.69e-10    1.23e-8   1.72e-10
5   1.16e- 9    6.38e-9    6.29e-8    1.47e-7    4.01e-8    2.32e-8    6.88e-8   7.74e-10    1.28e-8   1.66e-10
6   1.41e- 9    1.65e-7    3.88e-1    1.89e-7   10.00e-1    1.41e-8    2.16e-8   1.93e-10    1.16e-8   1.72e-10
7   7.85e-10    4.37e-9    1.43e-8    2.13e-8    4.11e-9    8.18e-9    1.14e-7  10.00e- 1   10.00e-1  10.00e- 1
8   7.35e-10    3.98e-9    1.84e-8    4.98e-8    9.34e-9    1.56e-8    1.11e-1   3.99e-10    3.64e-8   1.27e-10
# … with 40 more variables: ..2014.May <dbl>, ..2014.Jun <dbl>, ..2014.Jul <dbl>, ..2014.Aug <dbl>,
#   ..2014.Sep <dbl>, ..2014.Oct <dbl>, ..2014.Nov <dbl>, ..2014.Dec <dbl>, ..2015.Jan <dbl>, ..2015.Feb <dbl>,
#   ..2015.Mar <dbl>, ..2015.Apr <dbl>, ..2015.May <dbl>, ..2015.Jun <dbl>, ..2015.Jul <dbl>, ..2015.Aug <dbl>,
#   ..2015.Sep <dbl>, ..2015.Oct <dbl>, ..2015.Nov <dbl>, ..2015.Dec <dbl>, ..2016.Jan <dbl>, ..2016.Feb <dbl>,
#   ..2016.Mar <dbl>, ..2016.Apr <dbl>, ..2016.May <dbl>, ..2016.Jun <dbl>, ..2016.Jul <dbl>, ..2016.Aug <dbl>,
#   ..2016.Sep <dbl>, ..2016.Oct <dbl>, ..2016.Nov <dbl>, ..2016.Dec <dbl>, ..2017.Jan <dbl>, ..2017.Feb <dbl>,
#   ..2017.Mar <dbl>, ..2017.Apr <dbl>, ..2017.May <dbl>, ..2017.Jun <dbl>, ..2017.Jul <dbl>, ..2017.Aug <dbl>
```

However I would like to put the column names in the list as a row in the tibble above. So the expected output will be the same as the above output but with as extra column consisting of the 8 column names.

I tried adding `.id = ...` to the `bind_rows()` function without luck.

Data

```
myData <- list(`2013 Jul` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000586668967179058, AMD = 0.999999991491099, 
ADI = 0.00000000117911508574853, ABBV = 0.00000000265554743775555, 
A = 0.00000000115748600545925, APD = 0.00000000141026403514149, 
AA = 0.000000000784750220037462, CF = 0.00000000073506931568161
), `2013 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000648353317059087, AMD = 0.875365993858617, 
ADI = 0.0000000140110878459388, ABBV = 0.124633806310419, A = 0.00000000638412638183004, 
APD = 0.000000164595452907438, AA = 0.00000000437298323817569, 
CF = 0.00000000398380634004841), `2013 Sep` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000517932941811509, 
AMD = 0.612052960904497, ADI = 0.0000000263895584669299, ABBV = 0.000000309428734758588, 
A = 0.0000000629317056732015, APD = 0.387946555852345, AA = 0.0000000142868308895674, 
CF = 0.000000018412991125508), `2013 Oct` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000389953622626768, 
AMD = 0.999999478508266, ADI = 0.0000000276335723565588, ABBV = 0.0000000472396807220791, 
A = 0.000000147164957172584, APD = 0.000000189330239714144, AA = 0.0000000213345686039171, 
CF = 0.0000000497933442521737), `2013 Nov` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000134882594924129, 
AMD = 0.00000000852486962175739, ADI = 0.00000000555658190434702, 
ABBV = 0.0000000033994343633049, A = 0.0000000401316113485585, 
APD = 0.999999915449652, AA = 0.00000000410810324107976, CF = 0.00000000934149243627882
), `2013 Dec` = c(AAPL = 0.999999921441984, AMD = 0.00000000205795205438493, 
ADI = 0.00000000423942527570848, ABBV = 0.0000000111785276644757, 
A = 0.0000000231550299007735, APD = 0.0000000141357214257506, 
AA = 0.0000000081755174177734, CF = 0.000000015615836503074), 
    `2014 Jan` = c(AAPL = 0.888971396625332, AMD = 0.00000000687305696872764, 
    ADI = 0.0000000135348498626975, ABBV = 0.0000000368238505712531, 
    A = 0.0000000688076137965325, APD = 0.0000000216336902755598, 
    AA = 0.000000114183497113198, CF = 0.111028341518231), `2014 Feb` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000287503646141229, 
    AMD = 0.00000000017299912515279, ADI = 0.00000000020121937413004, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000268597317218042, A = 0.000000000774330625502137, 
    APD = 0.000000000193444545552257, AA = 0.999999997703134, 
    CF = 0.00000000039877049802864), `2014 Mar` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000848275956986802, 
    AMD = 0.0000000101635279442106, ADI = 0.00000000890671802341545, 
    ABBV = 0.0000000123427116789235, A = 0.0000000128226204295672, 
    APD = 0.0000000116011326797601, AA = 0.999999899248701, CF = 0.0000000364318073574497
    ), `2014 Apr` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000178638433702948, AMD = 0.000000000201400531551947, 
    ADI = 0.000000000170858232539827, ABBV = 0.00000000017214475074626, 
    A = 0.000000000166251996942934, APD = 0.000000000171547529586083, 
    AA = 0.999999998812376, CF = 0.000000000126784967469039), 
    `2014 May` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000825806016148428, AMD = 0.0000000242915432998119, 
    ADI = 0.00000000902664119089424, ABBV = 0.00000000896958354624411, 
    A = 0.0000000083777905585742, APD = 0.00000000865744715093347, 
    AA = 0.999999927255364, CF = 0.00000000516360459818763), 
    `2014 Jun` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000734100999564067, AMD = 0.0000000150503103256137, 
    ADI = 0.00000000757160064141869, ABBV = 0.00000000752654566025119, 
    A = 0.00000000920488818587725, APD = 0.00000000777588973470341, 
    AA = 0.999999941568228, CF = 0.00000000396155112883834), 
    `2014 Jul` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000119578338582021, AMD = 0.0000000190757084972887, 
    ADI = 0.0000000124551508506746, ABBV = 0.0000000126961984867664, 
    A = 0.0000000123508310694958, APD = 0.00000000690328396557648, 
    AA = 0.999999911719115, CF = 0.0000000128419142551259), `2014 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000646906408561993, 
    AMD = 0.000000001303588036132, ADI = 0.000000000747010166353616, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000809939898421209, A = 0.00000000062269403754113, 
    APD = 0.000000000823270056169483, AA = 0.999999988354505, 
    CF = 0.00000000086993291352539), `2014 Sep` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000901118220392747, 
    AMD = 0.00000000603735343176297, ADI = 0.00000000378512145849581, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000492519244094702, A = 0.00000000375282459701689, 
    APD = 0.00000000503099867563458, AA = 0.999999881793338, 
    CF = 0.00000000456335948026506), `2014 Oct` = c(AAPL = 0.999999998342956, 
    AMD = 0.000000000195198963169757, ADI = 0.000000000240015381676352, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000184703007590507, A = 0.000000000283879369466089, 
    APD = 0.0000000002704403119698, AA = 0.000000000249037261290181, 
    CF = 0.00000000023377012441852), `2014 Nov` = c(AAPL = 0.999999995039756, 
    AMD = 0.000000000183029820076064, ADI = 0.000000000444285807717282, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000545203064171254, A = 0.000000000520291866342424, 
    APD = 0.000000000710859506608269, AA = 0.00000000191423124920871, 
    CF = 0.000000000642343105905816), `2014 Dec` = c(AAPL = 0.999999995249817, 
    AMD = 0.000000000109663138429794, ADI = 0.000000000283239699166041, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000253526824211668, A = 0.000000000288982009691795, 
    APD = 0.000000000245503991889989, AA = 0.00000000100859772494323, 
    CF = 0.000000000278927871649668), `2015 Jan` = c(AAPL = 0.548118373387362, 
    AMD = 0.000000000270338711703369, ADI = 0.000000000776748222321511, 
    ABBV = 0.0000000243999618190709, A = 0.000000000647430017645498, 
    APD = 0.00000000165146468286352, AA = 0.00000000084119610220479, 
    CF = 0.451881598025498), `2015 Feb` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000550839494029532, 
    AMD = 0.000000000224431057557578, ADI = 0.000000000642567878702245, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000897791575951834, A = 0.000000000498886385267618, 
    APD = 0.000000000419805317431017, AA = 0.00000000048819610035365, 
    CF = 0.999999991319929), `2015 Mar` = c(AAPL = 0.68000607113785, 
    AMD = 0.00000000031822717876807, ADI = 0.00000000199652727037945, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000127616815956661, A = 0.000000000800272447770001, 
    APD = 0.00000000259052942770996, AA = 0.000000000465698346338894, 
    CF = 0.319993921414741), `2015 Apr` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000436360159538407, 
    AMD = 0.000000000605447129517975, ADI = 0.999999948835757, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000129608719630545, A = 0.00000000127146465671572, 
    APD = 0.00000000194029885408758, AA = 0.000000000642209093616402, 
    CF = 0.00000000177272268067319), `2015 May` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000245005073883088, 
    AMD = 0.000000000233066377451242, ADI = 0.999999997008782, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000498208702611887, A = 0.000000000502457143741384, 
    APD = 0.000000000547806981727115, AA = 0.000000000225823605106238, 
    CF = 0.000000000738851006789527), `2015 Jun` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000579400348232152, 
    AMD = 0.0000000017770566930171, ADI = 0.96317539082826, ABBV = 0.00000000309471150814288, 
    A = 0.00000000295196439965615, APD = 0.00000000392289074531856, 
    AA = 0.00000000137583562470442, CF = 0.0368245902552171), 
    `2015 Jul` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000268765784259825, AMD = 0.000000000368619127114303, 
    ADI = 0.000000000639129145047201, ABBV = 0.000000000547257200604174, 
    A = 0.000000000417286558654894, APD = 0.000000000421635615531905, 
    AA = 0.000000000182211224492934, CF = 0.999999997155096), 
    `2015 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000155223986626911, AMD = 0.000000000455688776102372, 
    ADI = 0.00000000756888774452725, ABBV = 0.999999986442286, 
    A = 0.00000000104291324702958, APD = 0.00000000116350848624178, 
    AA = 0.000000000327145665872367, CF = 0.00000000144733269080328
    ), `2015 Sep` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000509060404665308, AMD = 0.000000000167423393270364, 
    ADI = 0.000000000190108215158462, ABBV = 0.999999997373043, 
    A = 0.000000000450819674508831, APD = 0.000000000485618777766515, 
    AA = 0.000000000208163846577404, CF = 0.00000000061576315955172
    ), `2015 Oct` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000208300299141024, AMD = 0.0000000100600307297717, 
    ADI = 0.0000000127031721873714, ABBV = 0.999999897459721, 
    A = 0.0000000104078896103739, APD = 0.0000000102817159465299, 
    AA = 0.0000000183774281432957, CF = 0.0000000198800117767488
    ), `2015 Nov` = c(AAPL = 0.000000511650452995881, AMD = 0.000000112271950334638, 
    ADI = 0.219573489785576, ABBV = 0.000000132126315658583, 
    A = 0.0000000712278827829666, APD = 0.780425610769241, AA = 0.0000000120539749085508, 
    CF = 0.0000000601146061694847), `2015 Dec` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000145699888969055, 
    AMD = 0.122340004736447, ADI = 0.000000019159573174767, ABBV = 0.0000000156839685578602, 
    A = 0.877659921466186, APD = 0.00000000443064439569462, AA = 0.0000000102795965569221, 
    CF = 0.00000000967358600186237), `2016 Jan` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000205286719439008, 
    AMD = 0.55790216137549, ADI = 0.0000000223965710896714, ABBV = 0.0000000267935043263925, 
    A = 0.442097689496723, APD = 0.000000044622647624101, AA = 0.0000000252256379873006, 
    CF = 0.00000000956075364687753), `2016 Feb` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000238098866730783, 
    AMD = 0.999999607514308, ADI = 0.000000127857339122186, ABBV = 0.0000000231427648750923, 
    A = 0.000000125463927048533, APD = 0.0000000724117703188513, 
    AA = 0.0000000139802364993169, CF = 0.00000000581986359903877
    ), `2016 Mar` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000134902262402952, AMD = 0.848176180854655, 
    ADI = 0.0000000271825291039561, ABBV = 0.0000000168290505666805, 
    A = 0.151823705396409, APD = 0.0000000320891409964657, AA = 0.0000000190285725045248, 
    CF = 0.00000000512942270603603), `2016 Apr` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000525280746826918, 
    AMD = 0.999999955207798, ADI = 0.00000000629740469682576, 
    ABBV = 0.0000000070649297069453, A = 0.00000000981300601018476, 
    APD = 0.00000000949645275868385, AA = 0.00000000447779392490808, 
    CF = 0.0000000023898107586833), `2016 May` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000476925910252097, 
    AMD = 0.875218543005072, ADI = 0.00000000737352864661052, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000961152220481324, A = 0.00000000987259648603145, 
    APD = 0.0000000106598526904592, AA = 0.124781411263088, CF = 0.00000000344513009293904
    ), `2016 Jun` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000233822314264502, AMD = 0.999999974180517, 
    ADI = 0.00000000319793181566279, ABBV = 0.0000000058081254756031, 
    A = 0.00000000549929761858113, APD = 0.0000000046457114183394, 
    AA = 0.00000000305908916623466, CF = 0.00000000127116105985451
    ), `2016 Jul` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000395874096582675, AMD = 0.999999996670861, 
    ADI = 0.000000000554700138665486, ABBV = 0.000000000617688510949077, 
    A = 0.000000000604229861088835, APD = 0.000000000632338922598928, 
    AA = 0.000000000357580140796652, CF = 0.00000000016675079316293
    ), `2016 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000902238644696965, AMD = 0.999999992886332, 
    ADI = 0.00000000101775752912872, ABBV = 0.00000000106175415113571, 
    A = 0.00000000112109995645813, APD = 0.0000000010197683551329, 
    AA = 0.00000000132493521912968, CF = 0.000000000666142297875307
    ), `2016 Sep` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000247544480088939, AMD = 0.999999982857795, 
    ADI = 0.00000000259124594044507, ABBV = 0.00000000263590869088259, 
    A = 0.00000000271802756464799, APD = 0.0000000025961018252506, 
    AA = 0.00000000236370665980815, CF = 0.00000000176183742254325
    ), `2016 Oct` = c(AAPL = 0.0000000021640409658938, AMD = 0.999999984319123, 
    ADI = 0.00000000234757843065035, ABBV = 0.00000000255919093387747, 
    A = 0.0000000029041239375753, APD = 0.00000000219206665331904, 
    AA = 0.00000000215271552270588, CF = 0.00000000136120100682662
    ), `2016 Nov` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000580464296578016, AMD = 0.999999970611118, 
    ADI = 0.00000000500259684294652, ABBV = 0.00000000350606128040158, 
    A = 0.00000000434162176313208, APD = 0.0000000039129699233732, 
    AA = 0.00000000356942789862379, CF = 0.00000000325166941406765
    ), `2016 Dec` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000142958422924844, AMD = 0.999999988868272, 
    ADI = 0.00000000227081606055565, ABBV = 0.00000000109358361965842, 
    A = 0.00000000102347148214705, APD = 0.00000000144579838411725, 
    AA = 0.00000000252717010349114, CF = 0.00000000134130218000496
    ), `2017 Jan` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000236274501483694, AMD = 0.99999999828866, 
    ADI = 0.000000000264474716848254, ABBV = 0.000000000172277280065025, 
    A = 0.000000000172593183929414, APD = 0.000000000196829820802072, 
    AA = 0.000000000261288039963774, CF = 0.000000000407608841788685
    ), `2017 Feb` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000538580163047065, AMD = 0.458780262611877, 
    ADI = 0.00000000538918654816081, ABBV = 0.00000000261100269544006, 
    A = 0.00000000319930373731615, APD = 0.00000000331397396374686, 
    AA = 0.117293413296822, CF = 0.423926304192083), `2017 Mar` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000660741118663803, 
    AMD = 0.999999956653066, ADI = 0.00000000705239729637004, 
    ABBV = 0.00000000318883660353263, A = 0.00000000404173909160778, 
    APD = 0.00000000327254523618409, AA = 0.0000000131663147972097, 
    CF = 0.00000000601770292406702), `2017 Apr` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000415721053009824, 
    AMD = 0.999999997277344, ADI = 0.000000000421027638771769, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000278192049535268, A = 0.000000000317670807503632, 
    APD = 0.000000000251216546392771, AA = 0.000000000641546337428044, 
    CF = 0.000000000397287883591234), `2017 May` = c(AAPL = 0.000000000466735390337044, 
    AMD = 0.999999996491583, ADI = 0.000000000367501294273299, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000396066254548848, A = 0.000000000482638646660546, 
    APD = 0.00000000027021755403403, AA = 0.00000000120746228682863, 
    CF = 0.000000000317801404484393), `2017 Jun` = c(AAPL = 0.999999910071274, 
    AMD = 0.00000000253333998199778, ADI = 0.000000000453013272990588, 
    ABBV = 0.000000000581815713245697, A = 0.0000000847116475191311, 
    APD = 0.000000000542928532975976, AA = 0.000000000638963871008185, 
    CF = 0.000000000467014929339993), `2017 Jul` = c(AAPL = 0.00000000106561682474822, 
    AMD = 0.00000000157911720407928, ADI = 0.00000000137295355714574, 
    ABBV = 0.0000000016733524355219, A = 0.99999999062747, APD = 0.00000000104084478309771, 
    AA = 0.00000000195542301666525, CF = 0.000000000685222817624398
    ), `2017 Aug` = c(AAPL = 0.528902728550579, AMD = 0.238428416790421, 
    ADI = 0.0000000143314446548314, ABBV = 0.0000000453941921376418, 
    A = 0.232668766400542, APD = 0.0000000125809465872461, AA = 0.0000000101263676713084, 
    CF = 0.00000000582560448331477))
```

EDIT:

This seems to do "something" close to what I am trying to achieve but now I need the rownames to be the dates `2013 Aug`.... 2013.Nov` etc.

```
x <- transpose(myData)
names(x) <- c("AAPL", "AMD", "ADI",  "ABBV", "A",  "APD", "AA", "CF")
bind_rows(x)
```

Comment: If you're just adding that one column and it's always the same across your list you could do it manually,something like `mydata$vec = names(myData[[1]])`. More complicated solutions exist but I don't see anything wrong with that, seems short and clear.

Comment: You might be confused about list types when you say "the column names in the list". You have a list of named vectors, no column names, and if you're using a list the names don't have to line up between list elements.

Comment: I do see now that I have lists of named vectors and no column names. My work around currently is to manually enter the new column but I was hoping to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr` might be the way to do it.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  map_dfr(~ bind_rows(.), .id = "date")

# A tibble: 50 x 9
   date          AAPL       AMD      ADI     ABBV        A       APD        AA       CF
   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2013 Jul  5.87e-10 10.00e- 1 1.18e- 9 2.66e- 9 1.16e- 9  1.41e- 9  7.85e-10 7.35e-10
 2 2013 Aug  6.48e- 9  8.75e- 1 1.40e- 8 1.25e- 1 6.38e- 9  1.65e- 7  4.37e- 9 3.98e- 9
 3 2013 Sep  5.18e- 8  6.12e- 1 2.64e- 8 3.09e- 7 6.29e- 8  3.88e- 1  1.43e- 8 1.84e- 8
 4 2013 Oct  3.90e- 8 10.00e- 1 2.76e- 8 4.72e- 8 1.47e- 7  1.89e- 7  2.13e- 8 4.98e- 8
 5 2013 Nov  1.35e- 8  8.52e- 9 5.56e- 9 3.40e- 9 4.01e- 8 10.00e- 1  4.11e- 9 9.34e- 9
 6 2013 Dec 10.00e- 1  2.06e- 9 4.24e- 9 1.12e- 8 2.32e- 8  1.41e- 8  8.18e- 9 1.56e- 8
 7 2014 Jan  8.89e- 1  6.87e- 9 1.35e- 8 3.68e- 8 6.88e- 8  2.16e- 8  1.14e- 7 1.11e- 1
 8 2014 Feb  2.88e-10  1.73e-10 2.01e-10 2.69e-10 7.74e-10  1.93e-10 10.00e- 1 3.99e-10
 9 2014 Mar  8.48e- 9  1.02e- 8 8.91e- 9 1.23e- 8 1.28e- 8  1.16e- 8 10.00e- 1 3.64e- 8
10 2014 Apr  1.79e-10  2.01e-10 1.71e-10 1.72e-10 1.66e-10  1.72e-10 10.00e- 1 1.27e-10
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can `rbind` `myData` with `do.call` but it gives dates as rownames. You can make them as separate column and delete the rownames.

```
temp <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, myData))
temp$date  <- rownames(temp)
rownames(temp) <- NULL

temp
#         AAPL        AMD        ADI       ABBV          A        APD         AA         CF     date
#1  5.8667e-10 1.0000e+00 1.1791e-09 2.6555e-09 1.1575e-09 1.4103e-09 7.8475e-10 7.3507e-10 2013 Jul
#2  6.4835e-09 8.7537e-01 1.4011e-08 1.2463e-01 6.3841e-09 1.6460e-07 4.3730e-09 3.9838e-09 2013 Aug
#3  5.1793e-08 6.1205e-01 2.6390e-08 3.0943e-07 6.2932e-08 3.8795e-01 1.4287e-08 1.8413e-08 2013 Sep
#4  3.8995e-08 1.0000e+00 2.7634e-08 4.7240e-08 1.4716e-07 1.8933e-07 2.1335e-08 4.9793e-08 2013 Oct
#5  1.3488e-08 8.5249e-09 5.5566e-09 3.3994e-09 4.0132e-08 1.0000e+00 4.1081e-09 9.3415e-09 2013 Nov
#6  1.0000e+00 2.0580e-09 4.2394e-09 1.1179e-08 2.3155e-08 1.4136e-08 8.1755e-09 1.5616e-08 2013 Dec
#7  8.8897e-01 6.8731e-09 1.3535e-08 3.6824e-08 6.8808e-08 2.1634e-08 1.1418e-07 1.1103e-01 2014 Jan
#....
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can convert the to `data.frame` within the `list`, create a new column with `Map` and `rbind`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, date = names(myData),
     lapply(myData, as.data.frame.list)), make.row.names = FALSE))
head(out)
#      date         AAPL          AMD          ADI         ABBV            A          APD           AA           CF
#1 2013 Jul 5.866690e-10 1.000000e+00 1.179115e-09 2.655547e-09 1.157486e-09 1.410264e-09 7.847502e-10 7.350693e-10
#2 2013 Aug 6.483533e-09 8.753660e-01 1.401109e-08 1.246338e-01 6.384126e-09 1.645955e-07 4.372983e-09 3.983806e-09
#3 2013 Sep 5.179329e-08 6.120530e-01 2.638956e-08 3.094287e-07 6.293171e-08 3.879466e-01 1.428683e-08 1.841299e-08
#4 2013 Oct 3.899536e-08 9.999995e-01 2.763357e-08 4.723968e-08 1.471650e-07 1.893302e-07 2.133457e-08 4.979334e-08
#5 2013 Nov 1.348826e-08 8.524870e-09 5.556582e-09 3.399434e-09 4.013161e-08 9.999999e-01 4.108103e-09 9.341492e-09
#6 2013 Dec 9.999999e-01 2.057952e-09 4.239425e-09 1.117853e-08 2.315503e-08 1.413572e-08 8.175517e-09 1.561584e-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R one liner:

```
tmp <- data.frame(cbind(date = unlist(names(myData)), do.call(rbind, myData)), row.names = NULL)
```